# How to deploy typescript express app in cpanel?

Tags: typescript, cpanel

I have been trying to deploy a simple typescript based express application on cpanel. The deployment page has minimal options to configure and seems like it only supports for javascript node. The javascript node applications are working fine and are getting deployed. Can someone help me if it's possible for the typescript express app to be deployed on cpanel? Thanks in advance.[image]